# C# Serialize nested lists as XML

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class to XML that has a field of type List{List{String}} or String[][] or List{String[]}.  My class was serializing and deserializing fine before I added the nested collection field, but it is throwing an InvalidOperationException when serializing or deserializing now.

I don't really care if I have to use arrays or lists for this specific instance, but it would be nice to know a general solution that can be used for any nested collection situation.

---

Currently my field is declared like this:

```
[XmlElement("foo")]
public List<String[]> foo;
```

This has worked fine for me on single level lists and arrays in the past.

---

Here is the full class:

```
[XmlRoot("ColumnUpdaterPrefs")]
public class ColumnUpdaterPrefs : Prefs {

    public ColumnUpdaterPrefs() : base() {
        defaultHeaders = new List<String[]>();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("autoFill")]
    public Boolean autoFill = true;

    [XmlAttribute("allowErrors")]
    public Boolean allowErrors;

    [XmlAttribute("allowZeroes")]
    public Boolean allowZeroes;

    [XmlElement("defaultHeaders")]
    public List<String[]> defaultHeaders;

    [XmlElement("defaultKey")]
    public String defaultKey;

    public override Object Clone() { 
        return new ColumnUpdaterPrefs() {
            autoFill = this.autoFill,
            allowErrors = this.allowErrors,
            allowZeroes = this.allowZeroes,
            defaultHeaders = this.defaultHeaders,
            defaultKey = this.defaultKey
        }; 
    }
}
```

And its base class:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Prefs : ICloneable {

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public String name;

    public Prefs(String name = null) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String Serialize() {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType()); //InvalidOperationException occurs here
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            xs.Serialize(sw, this);
            var result = sw.ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static TPrefs Deserialize<TPrefs>(String xml) 
        where TPrefs : Prefs {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TPrefs)); //InvalidOperationException occurs here
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml)) {
            var result = (TPrefs)(xs.Deserialize(sr));
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Write(ApplicationSettingsBase settings, Boolean save = false, String name = null) {
        if (settings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settings");

        if (name == null) name = this.name;
        settings[name] = Serialize();
        if (save) settings.Save();           
    }

    public static TPrefs Read<TPrefs>(ApplicationSettingsBase settings, String name)
        where TPrefs : Prefs {

        if (settings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("settings");
        return Deserialize<TPrefs>((String)settings[name]);
    }

    public static TPrefs ReadOrDefault<TPrefs>(ApplicationSettingsBase settings, String name)
        where TPrefs : Prefs, new() {

        try { return Read<TPrefs>(settings, name); }
        catch { return new TPrefs() { name = name }; }
    }

    public abstract Object Clone();

}
```

---

Here are the exception details:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'*

---

Is there a simple way to do this without creating a custom collection class?

Comment: `I added the nested collection field,` Should we guess your classes and code (or are you going to post them)?

Comment: If I switch to List{List{String}} I get a CS0030, CS0029, and a second CS0030 error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the downvote, but it turns out the issue was just a matter of using the wrong attributes; something which could've been suggested based on my original code sample.

```
[XmlArray("outerList")]
[XmlArrayItem("innerList", typeof(List<String>))]
public List<List<String>> foo;
```